# Get several xml attributes from 1 element with xmllint

Tags: xml, bash

I have some XML code, which I get with curl. Further with pipes and xmllint I want to get values for attributes `rise` and `set` from tag `sun` and it should be in a format like 2018-10-01T07:02:40.
I tried 2 ways(in this samples I used file-xmlList.txt for simplification):

### 1

Input:

`echo 'cat //sun/@rise|//sun/@set' | xmllint --shell xmlList.txt`

Output

```
/ >  -------
 rise="2018-09-30T19:26:30"
 -------
 set="2018-10-01T07:02:40"
/ >
```

### 2

Input:

`xmllint --xpath 'string (//sun/@set) and string (//sun/@rise)' xmlList.txt`

Output

```
`true`
```

Can someone told me how can I get values in this format
file xmlList.txt -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<current>
<city id="2118647" name="Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky">
<coord lon="158.65" lat="53.02"></coord>
<country>RU</country>
<sun rise="2018-09-30T19:26:30" set="2018-10-01T07:02:40"></sun>
</city>
<temperature value="282.15" min="282.15" max="282.15" unit="kelvin"></temperature>
<humidity value="100" unit="%"></humidity>
<pressure value="992" unit="hPa"></pressure>
<wind>
<speed value="2" name="Light breeze"></speed>
<gusts></gusts>
<direction value="210" code="SSW" name="South-southwest"></direction> 
</wind>
<clouds value="92" name="overcast clouds"></clouds>
<visibility value="10000"></visibility>
<precipitation value="0.39" mode="rain" unit="3h"></precipitation>
<weather number="500" value="light rain" icon="10n"></weather>
<lastupdate value="2018-10-01T09:00:00"></lastupdate>
</current>
```

Answer (score 2):

The XPath below should return the values separated by a comma. Other output formatting should also be possible

```
xmllint --xpath 'concat(//sun/@rise,",",//sun/@set)' test.xml
```

Output:

```
2018-09-30T19:26:30,2018-10-01T07:02:40
```

To separate values with line break:

```
xmllint --xpath 'concat(//sun/@rise,"|",//sun/@set)' test.xml | tr '|' '\n'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It really works. Sorry for stupid question but could you explain me how I can separate values with line break? I tried write "\n" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Added that option. You can accept the answer if you want :) .